# Why does SonarQube is showing the message for all Java Streams: Refactor the code so this stream pipeline is used.?

Tags: java, sonarqube, java-stream, sonarlint, java-17

I have a Java project running in Java 17 version. I have pushed my code to the organization repository where `SonarQube` is running. In that repository, I am getting issues/bugs for all the `Java Streams List` that I have used in my project. Even for the simple ones.

Can someone please inform me why am I getting the issue for following Java Streams?

```
1. return input.stream().filter(Objects::nonNull).toList();

2. return input.stream().map(String::toLowerCase).toList();

3. return input.stream().filter(Objects::nonNull).map(i -> DOMAIN + "/" + i).toList();
```

For all the above mentioned Java Streams I am getting the following issue:

```
Refactor the code so this stream pipeline is used.
```

I tried to use the `.collect(Collectors.toList());` instead of `.toList();`, if I do that then my `Intellij/SonarLint` shows that I need to use the `.toList();`. So I am bit confused.

Can someone please tell me what's wrong with these Java Streams? I do not have any issue with this?

Comment: Could it be a bug in sonar? It could also be that it does not know about `toList()`, and might be looking at pre-Java17 logic.

Comment: [SONARJAVA-3784](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-3784) It was fixed in version 7.1 of the analyzer, included in SonarQube >= 9.0.  Try after updating your SonarQube version.

Comment: A clear case of wrong defaults. When Sonar doesn’t know a new method (like `toList()`), it should not issue a warning, especially not when this method doesn’t return `Stream`, so it’s very likely a terminal method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Posting the answer as it can be helpful to someone in the future:

This was happening because the SonarQube was using the old version. I updated the SonarQube and this error vanished.

The issue was happening in some 6.3.x version I updated it to 9.x version and everything is solved now.